# How do I extract variables that repeat from an Excel Column using Python?

Tags: python, pandas, pycharm, openpyxl, xlrd

I'm a beginner at Python and I have a school proyect where I need to analyze an excel document with information. It has aproximately 7 columns and more than 1000 rows.

Theres a column named "Materials" that starts at B13. It contains a code that we use to identify some materials. The material code looks like this -> 3A8356. There are different material codes in the same column they repeat a lot. I want to identify them and make a list with only one code, no repeating. Is there a way I can analyze the column and extract the codes that repeat so I can take them and make a new column with only one of each material codes?

An example would be:

```
12 Materials    
13 3A8356
14 3A8376
15 3A8356
16 3A8356
17 3A8346
18 3A8346
```

and transform it toosomething like this:

```
1 Materials
2 3A8346
3 3A8356
4 3A8376
```

Comment: @GrantMcCloskey that's a bit broad to the scope of the question, isn't it pal?

Comment: @J.C.Rocamonde He did not post code so I assume he has no base to work off of. yeah?

Comment: If a list of the unique entries is what you're after, look into [`pd.Series.unique`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unique.html)

Comment: It would be more productive if you try to address the problem first, write some code, get an specific question, and then come back

Comment: Please, take a look at my answer; I hope it helps you with your issue. And in the future, try to write a bit more concise questions so that people get a clear picture of your problem, and don't have to guess.

Comment: You should at least include some code demonstrating what you have tried: SO is not the place to get people to do your homework.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

If `df` is your dataframe, you only have to do `df = df.drop_duplicates(subset=['Materials',], keep=False)`

To load the dataframe from an excel file, just do:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel(path_to_file)
```

the subset argument indicates which column headings you want to look at.

Docs: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html

[image]

For the docs, the new data frame with the duplicates dropped is returned so you can assign it to any variable you want. If you want to re_index the first column, take a look at:

```
new_data_frame = new_data_frame.reset_index(drop=True)
```

Or simply

```
new_data_frame.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
```